# android outofmemeryerror when start an activity

Tags: android, fragment, out-of-memory

I have almost finish my app. but here is a problem puzzle me for a long time  sometimes 
It come out `OutOfMemeryError Exception`. it's sometimes appeared but  not always.

so ,I guess my app must manage memory for itself. but how to manager it?

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: It's an application and the outofmemory error appeared random .I can't fix the problem with an activity or a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OutOfMemoryException` is the worst kind of issue you can have (unless you're trying to load a 50MB image into RAM.
Basically, the way to handle those is to use the [Memory Analyzing Tool](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) and check what is preventing your memory from clearing when the GC is running.

In my case it was mostly the following issues:

1. [cyclic referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176745/1056359).
2. saving of data that needs to be cleared like duplicate instances.
3. too many singletons running.
4. duplicate instancing of objects.

try using the MAT and seeing what went wrong and optimize your code.

Sorry I can't give anything better than this, it the sad sad truth

Answer (score 0):

Handle Outofmemory error by using below code.

```
try{
}
catch (Throwable ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
// clear your memory
 }
 return null;
 }
```

Comment: how would that help? how would you clean memory

Comment: When you are using more memory or there may be chance of getting of OutofMemory you can use this exception. If you get the OutOfMemory then it will come into if condition of catch block, there you can clear your memory to avoid OutofMemory.

Comment: here's two question 1. here is so many function in my app.which method  shoud be use this try catch. 2. how to clear my memory could you tell a little bit more?with code is better!

Comment: For example if you are storing bitmaps in memory by using HashMap<String, Bitmap> and your setting images to your imageviews using Hashmap for better performance. Here there is chance of getting OutOfmemory because all bitmaps are stored in Memory itself. So if get OutOfMemory while adding Bitmaps to HashMap or setting bitmap to Imageview you can use this exception and in if condition of catch block you can clear the Hashmap.

Comment: @VenkataKrishna pls check this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html and this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: Use this wherever you are using more memory. clearing memory means if are storing anything in memory then clear that memory depending on your requirment.

Comment: @VenkataKrishna you don't allocate memory. You don't clear memory. its the job of garbage collecotr to free memory

Comment: @VenkataKrishna  thanks for your patience. may I use System.gc(); to clear memory?

Comment: @user2345457 no don't use system.gc(). its the job of garbage collector to free memory.. check the developer links i posted in the above comment

Comment: @user2345457 no don't use System.gc();. Intilize all objects to null. Try it. It may work.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your application has any memory leak. There are many tools for this e.g 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html or you can also use Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool ([MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/))

Else if your application genuinely requires a large amount of memory then you can try using the option "largeHeap" in the manifest file.

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    .
    .
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I wanna compatible my app from api8 to api17. so the attribute android:largeHeap can't be used. how can I  slove this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem case when you Intent to an Activity should use   Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  or it would oom

Comment: Actually in your case a lot of activities were remaining open and thus the when the stack get filled it causes OOM, OOM is one thing you can't handled by writing just a code it needs to be maintained through the application.