# Does Composite object's reciprocal relationship cause memory leak in java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Suppose we have following case. Should we face any memory leak here?

```
class A {
   B b;
   void set(B in) { b = in; }
}

class B {
  A a;
  void set(A in) { a = in; }
}

void main() {
   A ina = new A();
   B inb = new B();
   ina.set(inb);
   inb.set(ina);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, circular dependency can not cause memory leak in Java. Not sure whether that simply answers your question, you can take a look at the following for further discussions and explanations.

[Java: Is it bad practice to have a circular dependency within the same package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903870/java-is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-circular-dependency-within-the-same-package)

[Will this cause memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434474/will-this-cause-memory-leak)