# JavaFX and listener memory leaks

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, listener, javafx-8

I'm a bit confused about JavaFx 8 and the listener memory leak problem. The official [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-) says:

> The ObservableValue stores a strong reference to the listener which will prevent the listener from being garbage collected and may result in a memory leak.

I would like to have an example where the usage of `ObservableValue<T>` `addListener` method create a memory leak.

For example, if I have a class like this:

```
public class ConfigurationPane extends AnchorPane {
    @FXML
    private Label titleLabel;

    public ConfigurationPane () {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/ConfigurationPane .fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        titleLabel.sceneProperty().addListener(new MyListener());
    }
}
```

Can I get memory leaks? When a `ConfigurationPane` object is garbage collected, the `MyListener` object is garbage collected too? I'm not able to see a scenario where

> a strong reference to the listener will prevent the listener from being garbage collected

P.S. I see other S.O. questions about this but none of these helped me to understand the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that map which store your listener is not using weak references, and you have to remove listeners youself to avoid memory leaks.

In the example below LeakingListener objects will never be freed although corresponding TextFields being removed from scene:

```java
public class LeakListener extends Application {

    private static class LeakingListener implements InvalidationListener {

        private final TextField tf;
        private final int[] placeHolder = new int[50000]; // to simplify monitoring

        public LeakingListener(TextField tf) {
            this.tf = tf;
        }

        public void invalidated(Observable i) {
            tf.setText(tf.getText() + ".");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Pane root = new VBox(3);

        final Button btnType = new Button("Type in all");

        Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
        btnAdd.setOnAction((e) -> {
            TextField tf = new TextField();
            root.getChildren().add(tf);
            // memory leaking listener which never gets cleaned
            btnType.armedProperty().addListener(new LeakingListener(tf));
        });

        Button btnRemove = new Button("Remove");
        btnRemove.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            // find random TextEdit element
            Optional<Node> toRemove = root.getChildren().stream().filter((Node t) -> t instanceof TextField).findAny();
            // if any, and remove it
            if (toRemove.isPresent()) {
                root.getChildren().remove(toRemove.get());
            }
        });

        Button btnMemory = new Button("Check Memory");
        btnMemory.setOnAction((e) -> {
            System.gc();
            System.out.println("Free memory (bytes): " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(btnAdd, btnRemove, btnType, btnMemory);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 350);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If `ObservableValue` stores [weak reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to a listener, you wouldn't have a problem. It can be mimicked by next example:

```java
public class LeakListener extends Application {

    private static class NonLeakingListener implements InvalidationListener {

        // we need listener to don't hold reference on TextField as well
        private final WeakReference<TextField> wtf;
        private final int[] placeHolder = new int[10000];

        public NonLeakingListener(TextField tf) {
            this.wtf = new WeakReference<>(tf);
        }

        public void invalidated(Observable i) {
            if (wtf.get() != null) {
                wtf.get().setText(wtf.get().getText() + ".");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Pane root = new VBox(3);

        final Button btnType = new Button("Type in all");

        // Here is rough weak listeners list implementation
        WeakHashMap<TextField, NonLeakingListener > m = new WeakHashMap<>();
        btnType.armedProperty().addListener((e)-> {
            for (TextField tf : m.keySet()) {
                m.get(tf).invalidated(null);
            }
        });


        Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
        btnAdd.setOnAction((e) -> {
            TextField tf = new TextField();
            root.getChildren().add(tf);
            m.put(tf, new NonLeakingListener(tf));
        });

        Button btnRemove = new Button("Remove");
        btnRemove.setOnAction((e) -> {
            // find random TextEdit element
            Optional<Node> toRemove = root.getChildren().stream().filter((Node t) -> t instanceof TextField).findAny();
            // if any, and remove it
            if (toRemove.isPresent()) {
                root.getChildren().remove(toRemove.get());
            }
        });

        Button btnMemory = new Button("Check Memory");
        btnMemory.setOnAction((e)-> {
            System.gc();
            System.out.println("Free memory (bytes): " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(btnAdd, btnRemove, btnType, btnMemory);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 350);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why LeakingListener creates a leak? The problem is that it holds a strong reference to the tf TextField? So, in my example above, MyListener doesn't create leaks?

Comment: right, your example is safe. Leak may appear only if you dynamically add/remove components and use listeners with them.

Comment: Ok. Thank you but I still don't understand why if I dynamically add/remove components with listeners I create leaks. :-(

Comment: @SergeyGrinev I know this is very old, but the first example doesn't produce a memory leak--at least not on JDK/JavaFX 16. Further, isn't the GC supposed to detect cyclical references (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176745/circular-references-in-java)? According to the accepted answer in the linked question, even since Java 1.2, the GC was able to remove these cyclical dependencies. This begs the question as to why JavaFX documents potential memory leaks. Perhaps they use native code that must be free'd? I was wondering if you had any input on this.